# Separating massive files into subdirectory

Tags: file, architecture, directory

I have thousands of pdf files that are mostly accessed programmatically. They are academic documents, and their names start with `<the last name of the author in letter><optional digit(s) to distinguish different authors of the same name><period><year><optional letter(s) to distinguish different documents of the same author-year>`) like this:

```
Johns1.2000a.pdf
```

From the point of view of programming the relevant programs, it is easier if all these files are in a single directory.

However, when I occasionally open these files manually on a GUI file browser, the directory is so huge that the response of the file browser becomes slow. Because of that, I separated the files into subdirectories named after the initial letter of the file name (i.e., file `Johns....pdf` goes into subdirectory `J`, etc.). But

- I wonder whether it makes sense to do this,

and also have problems with this method.

- First, the file names are not evenly distributed with respect to the initial letter; some letters have more files starting with it and some have less.
- Second, if the collection of files grow, each subdirectory would become too large, and I would have to go into another level like `AA`, `AB`, ..., which

  - is arbitrary and ad hoc (I would have to manually add a level whenever I feel the subdirectories grew too big), and
  - the unbalanced distribution would become even worse (i.e., there would be rarely any files in directory `QQ`, but quite a lot in `KA`, for example).

In this situation,

1. Does it make any sense to make subdirectories at all? I only occasionally access the files manually, so I can live with the slow response on the file browser. From other points of view, it there any pros for doing so?
2. If it does make sense to create sudirectories, it there a method that does not have problems mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

Caution: I'm just thinking off the top of my head.  This is directed to your question #2 only.

Suppose you mapped each file name into its hash code, and stored the file in a directory structure based on hash codes?  For example,

```
str = "Johns1.2000a.pdf"

str.hash.abs.to_s.chars
  #=> ["5", "2", "2", "1", "9", "8", "0", "3", "1",
  #    "6", "9", "8", "3", "0", "8", "1", "5", "2"]
```

so this file might be stored as

```
/5/2/2/Johns1.2000a.pdf
```

You could employ rules such as the following:

- initially create directories `/1`, `/2`,..., `/9` and add files to these directories based on the first digit of the absolute value of their hash codes.
- when saving a file, if the subdirectory `d` already contains `N` files (`N` being a parameter), create subdirectories `/0`, `/1`, `/2`,..., `/9` of `d` and move each file in `d` to the appropriate subdirectory, based on its hash code.  In the example above, the file `Johns1.2000a.pdf` would be moved from `/5/2/2/Johns1.2000a.pdf` to `/5/2/2/1/Johns1.2000a.pdf`.
- to retrieve a file, bore down to the last subdirectory, based on the file's hash code.
- you could periodically walk the tree to see if any next-to-last-level-subdirectory `d` contained only empty subdirectories, in which case `d`'s subdirectories could all be deleted.  Alternatively, each directory could contain a file containing a count of the total number of files in its immediate subdirectories, which would be updated when files are added or deleted.  When the counter goes to zero the subdirectories could be deleted.

A couple of observations:

- this obviously requires that the algorithm for computing hash codes will not change in future.  If there is any possibility that could happen, you could use a custom hash code method.
- I assume the first few digits in the absolute value of the hash code will be nearly randomly distributed, but if not, the last few digits of the hash code surely would be.

Comment: This mostly solves the problem of uneven distribution (and the achoc-ness if the process can be automated). A (minor) problem is that it is not intuitively accessible manually. But maybe I am expecting too much.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an update to the question in future, after you implement a solution.